# TSQL to get next number of rows of data?

Tags: t-sql

Normally we use the TSQL TOP to get first number of rows of data like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myTable;
```

I am not sure if there is any way to get the next 10 and next 10, ... till to the end, just something paging. I cannot figure out. May be CTE statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using row_number() in SQL Server 2005:

[Paging Records Using SQL Server 2005 Database - ROW_NUMBER Function](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx)

... and here's the Google-search I used to find it:

[row_number() over paging](http://www.google.com/search?q=row_number%28%29+over+paging)